# How to programmatically create background for LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout which I would like to set a background programmatically. This background should be very simple, just two rectangles one next to each other. The width of the rectangles is only known at runtime. What would be the best way?

```
    ShapeDrawable done = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    done.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0));
    done.getPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);

    ShapeDrawable remaining = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    remaining.setBounds(new Rect(20, 0, 0, 0));
    remaining.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);

    LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{remaining, done});
    weightRow.setBackgroundDrawable(composite);
```

I have tried to create a compound drawable like this, where I've expected the remaining rectangle to start at position 20, but it just fills the whole layout.

Comment: I haven't worked with `LayerDrawable` much/in a while, but from what I remember, drawable containers like `LayerDrawable` may maintain or consolidate state among all the drawables in that container (like bounds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. After reading more posts I've realized, that simulating the android:top, left, ... from xml drawable, you should use the setLayerInset(int index, int l, int t, int r, int b) of the LayerDrawable on the layer you want to shift.

```
ShapeDrawable done = new ShapeDrawable();
done.getPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);

ShapeDrawable remaining = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
remaining.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);

LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{done, remaining});
composite.setLayerInset(1, 0, 0, 100, 0);

layout.setBackgroundDrawable(composite);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom class that extends [`ShapeDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html). Implement the `onDraw()` method to define how it should draw itself; you cant programmatically draw your rectangular regions using the [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) APIs. You can then define a method to set the widths of those regions at runtime.

In your `Activity`, make a new instance of this class and call `setBackgroundDrawable()` on the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I've already tried that, but the trouble is that it scales the border between the rectangles so it looks blurry and i want a nice sharp edge.

Comment: Wouldn't that have to do with your drawing code? I can't think of a better way to accomplish what you want, unless you just put two `View`s inside a LinearLayout and change their layout weights at runtime (which is much more expensive as it requires an entire traversal of the view hierarchy to re-measure and layout the views before the redraw, whereas my suggestion only involves the redraw)

Comment: Its a scaling issue i believe, the border between the rectangles is lets say antialiased.. Anyway.. I have the screen width, so the scaling on x-axis won't happen.. So I'll make it that way. But i would still like to see comment on my question. Shouldn't it work ? I believe it should.